# How to get values of some specific range of keys in HashMap in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

How to get values of some specific range of keys in `HashMap` in Java?
Suppose I have a `HashMap` having keys and values as follows:

```
Map <Integer , String> map = hnew HashMap <Integer , String>();

map.put(1 , "A");
map.put(3 , "C");
map.put(2 , "B");
map.put(4 , "D");
map.put(5 , "E");
map.put(6 , "F");
```

Now how should I iterate to get values for keys `2` to `5` (that is `2`, `4`, and `5` but   *not* `3`)?

Comment: A `Map` is *not ordered*. So it does not matter if you `put` `2` after `3`.

Comment: Yes, that i know. Recently similar qn was asked in interview they asked how i should iterate to get values in order (as they stored).

Comment: If you use a `Map` and a `HashMap`, the answer is: you can't.

Comment: What you want sounds like a [NavigableMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html). Java has you covered, it has methods like `subMap(first, second)` which gives you all entries in a given range of keys.

Comment: In case your keys stay like this, i.e. ascending integers without too many gaps, you may also use an `ArrayList`, where the key is the index implicitly. Then you can do `subList`.

Answer (score 3):

Either:

1. Loop through the list of keys you want and query the `HashMap` for the value corresponding to that key (be aware some may be null).
2. Loop through the `entrySet` of the `HashMap` looking to see if the key is one that you want.
3. Use a map that keeps order (`LinkedHashMap` added in correct order) and iterate through, extracting the required block of entries.

Comment: What about a [NavigableMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html)? Sounds like what OP is asking for.

Comment: @Zabuza Yes, that would be a good way to do it, you should add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

While Java's `Map` interface does not define a special order on its elements, a map implementation may very well define one. The sub-interface [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html) defines that all keys must be naturally ordered and adds new methods like [`subMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html#subMap(K,K)) to access value ranges. The sub-sub-interface [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) adds even more.

The most prominent implementation in Java's standard library of `SortedMap` is [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html):

```java
SortedMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();

map.put(1 , "A");
map.put(3 , "C");
map.put(2 , "B");
map.put(4 , "D");
map.put(5 , "E");
map.put(6 , "F");

System.out.println(map.subMap(2, 6).values()); // [B, C, D, E]
```

Answer (score -1):

A `Map` has no order on the keys. It does not matter if you `put` the key `3` and then the key `2`. This "order" is not preserved.

I don't see anything special about the keys 2, 4, and 5. So you could do this:

```
for (int key : new int[] {2, 4, 5}) {
  String value = map.get(key);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want maintain the order of the insertion for map then use LinkedHashMap. Then you can iterate the map through the specific value . 
Declare an array of Integer for which you would like the value.

```
int a[] = {2,4,5};
for(int i : a) {
String str = map.get(i);
doSomething(str); //method to operate on that string.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have a predictable order in the keys of a `Map`, you need to use subclass `LinkedHashMap`.

Here's an example of code that does what you want:

```
public class Snippet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();

        map.put(1, "A");
        map.put(3, "C");
        map.put(2, "B");
        map.put(4, "D");
        map.put(5, "E");
        map.put(6, "F");

        System.out.println(valuesBetween(2, 5, map));
    }

    public static List<String> valuesBetween(int from, int to, LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> map) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean inRange = false;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey() == from)
                inRange = true;
            if (inRange)
                result.add(entry.getValue());
            if (entry.getKey() == to)
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
[B, D, E]
```

Comment: Or you could use `TreeMap<Integer, String>`  and just call `subMap(2, 6);` :/

Answer (score -1):

```
    if you want get int key values from HashMap 
    you should create new Set Array and put values to it.

    **Set has specificity for sort it's keys**.

    Map<Integer,String> students = new HashMap<>();

    students.put(1, "Rashid");
    students.put(3, "Cosqun");
    students.put(2, "Ulvi");

    Set<Integer> keys = students.keySet();

    for (int key : keys) {
        System.out.println(key+" "+students.get(key));
    }
```

Comment: Add some explanation along with your code. Code only answers wouldn't be much useful without it.

Answer (score -2):

Dog, this is all you need:

```
SortedMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
map.subMap(2, 6);
```